# In how many different ways can the letters of the word 'OPTICAL' be arranged so that the vowels always come together?

Tags: combinatorics

In the below solved problem, every thing is okay, but if we have $4$ consonants then why we are giving $5!$? and is this a combination problem? how to distinguish?

Question:
In how many different ways can the letters of the word 'OPTICAL' be arranged so that the vowels always come together?

Answer:
The word 'OPTICAL' contains $7$ different letters.
When the vowels OIA are always together, they can be supposed to form one letter.
Then, we have to arrange the letters PTCL (OIA).
Now, $5$ letters can be arranged in $5! = 120$ ways.
The vowels (OIA) can be arranged among themselves in $3! = 6$ ways.
Required number of ways $= (120*6) = 720$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $4$ consonants and $1$ group of vowels, so there are $5$ elements to permute. Yes, this is a combinatorial problem because we are counting the number of possibilities that satisfy certain conditions.

Comment: Thanks fahrbach. One thing more.. Can I find the combination of word MATHEMATICS where r choices are not given?

Comment: @user160285, I don't understand what you're asking. My guess is that you can find it though.

Comment: I wanted to know that can we find the number of combinations of the letters of the word "MATHEMATICS"?

Comment: Oh, all of the permutations (anagrams) of the word "MATHEMATICS"? So, "MATHEMATICS", "AMTHEMATICS", etc.? Yes, you can.

Comment: No i didn't ask that, actually i am asking a foolish thing. I know. Well thanks fahrbach..

Comment: Okay, no problem. Good luck with your next problem!

Answer (score 0):

- OPTICAL has 7 letters - 3 vowels-OIA and 4 consonants-PTCL.
- 3 vowels has to stay together, thus possibilities of combinations is 3! = 6.
- Apply same rule to consonants as above, hence 4! = 24.
- Total length of a word with 7 letters where 3 vowels have to stay together is 5, considering vowels as one whole letter. Therefore, vowel letter can be placed in 5 different positions, as V----, -V----, --V-- and ---V- and ----V.
- Therefore, 3!(vowel combinations) * 4!(consonants combinations) * 5(positions) = 720.

Answer (score -1):

For this problem I use the multinomial coefficient.
We have 7 letters in total 3 of which are vowels and 4 are consonants

The number of vowels combinations are 3! and the number of consonants combinations are 4! (I've used the multinomial coefficient)
So by the end we've 3!*4! ways

Comment: You're missing a factor of $5$, because there are $5$ ways to place the clump of $3$ vowels among the $4$ consonants.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the correction :)